# Having a powershell script restart

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I created to query services that are running on servers in my environment. As it stands now, the script will work, returning running services then stop. I am trying to figure out a way to have the script go back to the beginning and prompt for the next server name so I can repeatedly execute it

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Name'
Get-Service -ComputerName $Server | Where Status -eq "Running"
Out-GridView
Read-host "press enter to continue.."
```

Comment: `while ($true) { Read-Host "You'll need Ctrl-C to stop this." }`

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to **pipe** the objects returned to `Out-GridView`.. ;)

I'd probably do something like this:

```
while ($true) { 
    $Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Name'
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Server)) { break }
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Server | 
    Where Status -eq "Running" |
    Out-GridView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will run until you just press enter instead of providing a servername.

```
$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Name'

while ($Server -ne "")  
{
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Server | Where Status -eq "Running" | Out-GridView
    $Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Server Name'
}
```

Comment: @ITninja777 I updated my code with a prettier solution

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the while statement in the loop made all the difference, it works great!